# epoll issue: tunneling and multi-threading

Tags: multithreading, tcp, epoll

I encounter this problem while trying to do TCP tunnelling between two threads.

```
Thread 1
  listen at Port
  accept
  then add the sock after accept to epoll_ctl
  while (1)
    epoll_wait
    read whatever from Port to remote (tunnelling)


Thread 2
  connect to Port
  if connected 
    communicate...
```

What I actually observe is: while Thread 2 is blocked on connect, Thread 1 has no chance to run epoll_wait and send the connect info to the remote. Thus both threads cannot make progress.

One possible solution is to use parent-child processes instead of multi-threading. But before I switch to that, could it still be done with multi-threading? I think what it is needed here is some kind of interrupt thing than just polling. Right?

Thank you for the insight.

Comment: Your code is fine as pseudo-written, and thread 2 will certainly run while 1 is stuck in the accept. Perhaps post actual code?

Answer (score 0):

You can add server side socket descriptor into epoll_ctl. But I'm curious that if thread2 blocked on connection, what information you need to send to server? Thanks for your hint.